# Sidekiq: How to assign process to a worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, backgroundworker, background-process, sidekiq

I'm having bit struggle in Sidekiq with multiple workers and multiple Sidekiq processes.

I'ld like to run three sidekiq processes for a environemt.

I'm having three workers class (Lets say **"worker1", "worker2" and "worker3"**) and three sidekiq processes (Lets say **"process1", "process2" and "process3"**).

> In my current structure the workers are running on any process which is available. But what I want is the **worker1** should run on **process1** and **worker2** should run on **process2** and so on.

I'm bit confused about achieving it and I'll be glad if I know how to set a worker to a particular sidekiq process.

Sidekiq processes are:

```
process1: bundle exec sidekiq -q default
process2: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/myapp_sidekiq.yml
process3: bundle exec sidekiq -q process3
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you asking a question about queues? https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#queues

Comment: Hi Krishna, its not about the queues. I'm having multiple queues running. Its about the Sidekiq process (Like I want to run 3 sidekiq process each should point to a worker)

Answer (score 3):

You assign processes to pull jobs from queues.  You assign workers to go into queues.

```
process1: bundle exec sidekiq -q queue1

class Worker1
  sidekiq_options queue: 'queue1'
end

# will only be processed by process1
Worker1.perform_async
```

Comment: I've dynamic queues for a process. So, It is not possible to  set a single queue for the worker like you mentioned.

Comment: Use `Sidekiq::Client.enqueue_to` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/client.rb#L148

Comment: I've used `Sidekiq::Client.push` to queue the process. `Sidekiq::Client.push('queue' => account_name_as_queue_name, 'class' => MyWorker, 'args' => [ raw_event.account_id ])`. In that, can I specify the process name of the Sidekiq like `Sidekiq::Client.push('process' => 'process1', 'queue' => raw_event.account_id, 'class' => EventProcessingWorker, 'args' => [ raw_event.account_id ])` to map the worker to the Sidekiq process.

Comment: reference to the document: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#reserved-queues